# Finding the center of application - VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am wanting to find the center of my application. Please read before saying Me.Width / 2..

I am loading a web page that has a Java based app in it and am wanting to automatically click the, 'login', button once the page has loaded. The VB app is a set size, but will not be maximized allowing the user to move the app around the screen. What I was thinking was doing something like..

```
SetCursorPos({CenterOfApp.Width} + 20, {CenterOfApp.Height})
```

..and then simulating a mouse click.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit 1 - I believe the answer could be below, I am just not sure of the formula required. Again I say, this is a fixed sized VB.net application loading a fixed sized Java application threw the VB.net browser control. The button will always be in the same location of the VB.net app, but the VB.net app will not always be in the same location of the computer screen. Meaning, I will need to find the center of the VB.net app depending on where it is on the screen of the computer.

```
Dim ScreenWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
Dim ScreenHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
Dim ClientLeft As Integer = Me.Location.X
Dim LeftOfScreenToApp As Integer ' This is to be the distance from the left side of the screen to the left side of the VB app.
LeftOfScreenToApp = ...
SetCursorPos(LeftOfScreenToApp + (Me.Width / 2) + 20, Me.Height / 2)
```

Comment: As I said, it is a Java application that I am loading in the web browser. Is there a way to read the Java application to find the login button as there is with html?

Comment: The odds that the button is in the center of the app are very low.  In Winforms, use HtmlElement.ClientRectangle and Control.PointToScreen()

Comment: The button will be in the center of the app + 20 pixels.. My question wasn't is the login button that I want to click not in the middle of the app.. Read my edit to the question, I believe the included vars may be able to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So happens that I was just overlooking the fact that Me.Location.X is the offset from left of screen to the left of the VB.net app, so..

```
Dim LeftOfScreenToLeftOfApp As Integer = Me.Location.X
Dim MiddleOfApp As Integer = LeftOfScreenToLeftOfApp + Me.Width / 2
```

..gets the center of the app no matter where it is located on the screen.